# How to call Firebase data through Vue.js Search Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, search

```js
Vue.component('search', {
  template: '\
<form class="form-inline">\
<div class="input-group input-group-lg"">\
<input v-model="search" class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" type="search" id="example-search-input" placeholder="Search your craves">\
<span class="input-group-append">\
<div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">\
<i class="fa fa-search" @click="searchButton()" style="cursor:pointer"></i>\
</div>\
</span>\
</div>\
</form>'
});

var search = new Vue({
  el: "#searchFunc",
  data: {
    allSearch: [],
    search: ""
  },
  methods: {
    async searchButton() {
      var search = await firestore.collection('koreanbap-cuisines');
      var query = await search.where("food_name", "==", "Pancake").get();

      // do exactly like getall
      var arr = [];
      query.forEach((docs) => {
        var obj = docs.data();

        arr.push(obj);
        console.log(obj);
      })
      this.allSearch = arr;
      console.log(this.allSearch);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="searchFunc">
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white fixed-top pb-3">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koreanban-2019.appspot.com/o/logo_images%2Flogo.svg?alt=media&token=75a8ef65-e3ee-4b57-b233-05c677853dee" width="150px">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
     </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item pt-3 px-3 d-md-flex justify-content-center">
            <search></search>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-4">
            <a href="index.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
              <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon - home.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto d-lg-block d-md-block d-sm-block">
         </span>Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-4">
            <a href="cuisuine.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
              <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon%20-%20cuisuine.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto d-lg-block d-md-block">
         </span>Cuisine
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-4">
            <a href="suggestion.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
              <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon - Suggestion.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto  d-md-block d-lg-block">
         </span>Suggestion
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item px-4">
            <a href="admin.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
              <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon - Contact.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto d-md-block d-lg-block">
         </span>Admin Login
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- Search Result -->

<div id="searchFunc" v-for="s in allSearch">
  <div v-bind:obj="allSearch">
    {{s.food_name}}
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="p-3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2019 Korean Bop</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
        <i class='fas fa-envelope fa-md'></i>
        <span>KoreanBop@gmail.com |</span>
        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-md"></i>
        <span>778-836-2243</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I need help with making a search function using Vue.js. I need to search cuisines title which are stored inside the firebase database.

[image: search function]

This is a page where my search function is located at

[image]

This is where the search function is used. The function will be triggered on a click-event to show the name of cuisine title.

[image]

This is where the result is going to be shown.

Currently when I click the button, I get these two errors.

[image]

I do not know how to solve these errors and don't know where to start from here. Any types of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATED**

So I changed searchButton function into

[image]

I have my v-model inside the search input (which should define the search) and I still get the same errors...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please include your code and errors as text instead of images.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
methods:{
  searchButton: async function (){
         ...
   }
 }
```

With :

```
methods:{
  async searchButton(){
     ...
    }
}
```

I think you need to read again vue js documentation.
In my example you need only to update your firebase config.

This is hour your code need to look:

```js
Vue.component('search-form', {
        data: function() {
            return {
                search: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async searchButton() {
                let query = await firestore.collection('koreanbap-cuisines').where("food_name", "==", "Pancake").get();
                query.forEach((docs) => {
                    this.allSearch.push(docs.data());
                });
                console.log(this.allSearch);
            }
        },
        template: '\
            <form class="form-inline">\
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg"">\
                <input class="form-control py-2 border-right-0 border" v-model="search" type="text" placeholder="Search your craves">\
                <span class="input-group-append">\
                <div class="input-group-text bg-transparent">\
                <i class="fa fa-search" @click="searchButton()" style="cursor:pointer"></i>\
                </div>\
                </span>\
                </div>\
            </form>'
    });
    let app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            allSearch: [],
        },

    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white fixed-top pb-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/koreanban-2019.appspot.com/o/logo_images%2Flogo.svg?alt=media&token=75a8ef65-e3ee-4b57-b233-05c677853dee"
                     width="150px">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item pt-3 px-3 d-md-flex justify-content-center">
                        <search-form></search-form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-4">
                        <a href="index.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
         <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon - home.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto d-lg-block d-md-block d-sm-block">
         </span>Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-4">
                        <a href="cuisuine.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
         <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon%20-%20cuisuine.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto d-lg-block d-md-block">
         </span>Cuisine
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-4">
                        <a href="suggestion.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
         <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon - Suggestion.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto  d-md-block d-lg-block">
         </span>Suggestion
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item px-4">
                        <a href="admin.html" class="nav-link text-sm-center text-lg-center text-md-center">
         <span>
          <img src="assets/icons/icon - Contact.png" class="m-3 mx-md-auto d-md-block d-lg-block">
         </span>Admin Login
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div v-for="s in allSearch">
        {{s.food_name}}
    </div>
    <footer class="p-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; 2019 Korean Bop</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
                    <i class='fas fa-envelope fa-md'></i>
                    <span>KoreanBop@gmail.com |</span>
                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-md"></i>
                    <span>778-836-2243</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have one more error to fix which is "Property or method "searchButton" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.." I have looked at similar questions regarding this error but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Please update your post with your current code to se exactly what you did. What I have answer to you need to solve the first error you have post

Comment: Can you post also your full html where you bind vue element? Maybe you can use code snipper to be more easy to understand your code?

Comment: I have update my answer. Hope my example will give start point. You can clean your first post and let only useful info without images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190194/discussion-between-julian-and-yong-jun-jung).